# Prove and generalize $\cos\frac\pi9\cos\frac{2\pi}9\cos\frac{3\pi}9\cos\frac{4\pi}9=\frac1{16}$

Tags: trigonometry, products

Is there a simple proof for the following?
$$16\cos\frac\pi9\cos\frac{2\pi}9\cos\frac{3\pi}9\cos\frac{4\pi}9=1$$
Is this statement valid for any odd number (not only 9)?

Is $\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$ useful in this case?

Comment: It's also true that $16cos(\pi/5)*cos(2\pi/5)cos(3\pi/5)cos(4\pi/5)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the given product by $2^4 \sin \frac{\pi}{9}$ and using the double-angle formula $\sin (2x)=2\sin x\cos x$ reduces the product one by one yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
\because \quad & 2^4 \sin \frac{\pi}{9} \cos \frac{\pi}{9} \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9} \cos \frac{3 \pi}{9} \cos \frac{4 \pi}{9} \\
= & 2^3 \sin \frac{2 \pi}{9} \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \cos \frac{4 \pi}{9} \\
= & 2 \sin \frac{4 \pi}{9} \cos \frac{4 \pi}{9} \\
= & \sin \frac{8 \pi}{9} \\
= & \sin \frac{\pi}{9}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\therefore \quad \sin \frac{\pi}{9} \cos \frac{\pi}{9} \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9} \cos \frac{3 \pi}{9} \cos \frac{4 \pi}{9}=\frac{1}{2^4}=\frac{1}{16}
$$